# Show column header of a table inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have this `JTable` with a search `JTextField`:
[image]
My problem is that the header of the `JTable` is not shown.

I create a `JPanel searchPanel` where I put a `JLabel "Search:"` and the `JTextField`. Then I create another `JPanel` to put the `JTable` and the `searchPanel`:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JTextField search = new JTextField();
JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("Search:");

searchPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);
searchPanel.add(search,BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(searchPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

At the end I put the `Jpanel panel` inside my `JScrollPane()`:

```
this.setViewportView(panel);
```

What can I do to show the column header?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use ScrollPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for a working example. Keep the tutorial link handy for Swing basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `setColumnHeaderView()` you can set the header of your scroll pane.

```
scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader());
```

And if you don't want to set header to scrollpane, then you need an extra panel for showing table with its header.

```
JPanel tablePanel =new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
tablePanel.add(table);
```